# Find cmake target name for a file

Tags: cmake

Given the file path for a translation unit, how can I get the target name(s) for it?

More formally:

Given: `path=/some/path/to/file/foo.cpp` and a `CMakeLists.txt` which specifies a `module_name` and has an entry for `foo.cpp`

Needed: A function which takes `path` and outputs the `module_name`.

Besides `CMakeLists.txt`, I also would have `compile_commands.json` at disposal.

Answer (score 0):

On the end of CMakeLists.txt, iterate over `BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS` directory property, for each target get list of `SOURCES` and see if one of them is the path.